# Extra padding in a div, next to the img

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I searched here about similar issues, but I couldn't find the solution for my problem.

I have a `#main-container` with `padding`. Inside I have few divs, with an `img`. The parent `div` of the `img` should has same height and width, but unfortunately it has extra space on the right side. Once I remove the padding of the `#main-container` everything works fine. I spent hours with it and I didn't find the solution.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-container {
    padding:30px;
    background:gray;
    height: 350px;
}

#right {
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    margin:0 5%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

#image-container {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

I created a jsfiddle example. The red represents the `#right` div, the black represents the parent container of the `img`. http://jsfiddle.net/0y1n6rnq/1/

[image]

Why is it happens?
Update: The problem occurs in firefox.

Comment: Not sure what you want your layout to look like

Comment: As I wrote the #image-container should have same width.

Comment: It is the same width for me

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the problem occurs in Firefox.

Comment: Ah, ok, well the reason this happens is because max-height is set to 100% on your img. Therefor your image will only be maximum 100% height of the container, so it will have a space if the container gets wider than the image width

Comment: The problem is with the width. For some reason it gets extra space.

Comment: What does `width: 50%` do? It is the source of your problem.

Comment: It reduces the size of my sidebar to 50%. I have an other div on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Setting max-width does nothing unless the image is sized above 100%, so you need to tell it to stretch the full length, add with: 100% to img class and it will be fixed :)

```
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it covers the black part of the div but when I use my portrait photo as an example I will look fat. :) (The image will not keep the ratio, it will be stretched)

Comment: Yes, its either that, or overflow: hidden. If you want to keep ratio, then part of the image needs to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. If we use max-height and width together image will stretch fatty. So if we make width: 100% then good to use height:auto

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-container {
    padding:30px;
    background:gray;
    height: 350px;
}

#right {
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    margin:0 5%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image-container {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="right">
        <div id="image-container">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/600/">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't resize the image, just cropped with overflow:hidden; I'm afraid it's not the best solution. I want to resize.

Comment: As i said previously, its either hide part of image, or stretch it. Anything else is just not possible. Unless the height of the box its in can be resized.